# What does this JAGS error mean? "Error in Slicer: Current value is inconsistent with data"

Tags: r, jags

I'm using JAGS and R, linked via rjags and R2jags, to fit a series of models.  The models are all the same except for the number of dimensions on one particular latent variable.  (I can supply more detail if needed.)

When I run the R script, the first iteration executes without problems.  But when the script gets to the second model, it crashes like so:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
   Graph Size: 51742

Deleting model

Error: RUNTIME ERROR:
Error in Slicer: Current value is inconsistent with data
```

I can't find any documentation for this error.  What does it mean, and how can I fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of one of your models so that it makes your question more relevant here than on stackoverflow?

Comment: @chl Well, it looks like an error in very specific statistic software to me...

Comment: Several readers have flagged this question as off-topic on CV and more appropriate for SO.  Because this question has not been clarified in response to @chl's request, SO is the place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this error before when the initial values for stochastic nodes are inconsistent with their parents. For instance if you have **X ~ Binomial(p,10)** and the starting value is either greater than 10 (or < 0) or is not an integer.  Does that help?